# ApiController Get Method Response Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Say I have an `ApiController` with the following method:

```
[HttpGet]
IEnumerable<MyType> GetSomeOfMyType( )
{
    return new MyType[ 10 ];
}
```

And I want to modify one of the response headers, how would I go about converting this method to allow that?

I'm guessing I need to manually create a response and serialise my data into it, but how?

Thanks.

Comment: what header you want to modify ? to what ?

Comment: The more specific/ detailed the question is, the more chances of getting correct answers

Comment: But at the end of the day a header is a header. In this particular case I'm interested in modifying the `Location:` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of returning `IEnumerable`, you should return `HttpResponseMessage` like below code, then you can modify its `Headers`:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSomeOfMyType( )
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new MyType[10]);

    //Access to header: response.Headers       

    return response;
}
```

Comment: The actual situation is that I am being passed the `HttpResponseMessage` to my function and so I had to use the `HttpResponse.CreateContent()` method. But this pointed me in the right direction (and answers the question I asked!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations):

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product item)
{
    item = repository.Add(item);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

    string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[HttpGet]
ActionResult GetSomeOfMyType( )
{
    ...
    HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("your_header_name", "your_header_value");
    ...

    return Json(new MyType[ 10 ]);
}
```

Assuming you're using JSON for serialization. Otherwise you can use `ContentResult` class and your custom serialization function, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
ActionResult GetSomeOfMyType( )
{
    ...
    HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("your_header_name", "your_header_value");
    ...

    return new ContentResult { 
        Content = YourSerializationFunction(new MyType[ 10 ]), 
        ContentEncoding = your_encoding, // optional
        ContentType = "your_content_type" // optional
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4. I don't seem to have access to the HttpContext.

Comment: It was accessible through Controller.HttpContext property at least in ASP.NET MVC 3 - I'm actually using it in my project written on MVC 3: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: The original question is asking about a ApiController  (WebApi), not an Mvc-Controller.  Thus the downvote you received.  (Not from me, just pointing it out).